# Convert nested lists to dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, dictionary-comprehension

I need to convert the  nested list `result = [[450, 455, 458], [452, 454, 456, 457], [451, 453]]` to a dictionary like:

```
{
    0: 
         {
             450: None,
             455: 450,
             458: 450
         },
    1:   {
             452: None,
             454: 452,
             456: 452,
             457: 452
         },
    2:   {
             451: None,
             453: 451
         }

}
```

**Please take a look at this and assist:**

```
result_group = {}
for sub_group in result:
    group_count = 0
    first_rel_item = 0
    result_group[group_count] = dict()
    for item in sub_group:
        if item == sub_group[0]:
            result_group[group_count][item] = None
            first_rel_item = item
            continue
        result_group[group_count]['item'] = first_rel_face
        group_count += 1
```

I messed up with this as i get key Error:1 cant add to dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
result_group = {}
group_count = 0
for sub_group in result:
    first_rel_item = 0
    result_group[group_count] = {}
    result_group[group_count][sub_group[0]] = None
    previtem = sub_group[0]
    for item in sub_group[1:]:
        result_group[group_count][item] = previtem
        previtem = item
    group_count += 1
```

Comment: Just tried I got this. [link](https://prnt.sc/itdgor) but I need the one like I mentioned in top. Your advice welcome

Comment: very strange, as i got `{0: {450: None, 455: 450, 458: 450}, 1: {452: None, 454: 452, 457: 452}, 2: {451: None, 453: 451}}`

Comment: using Python 3.6.3

Comment: make sure that the spaces are right - i.e. group_count should *not* be in the inner loop

Comment: I got what I need from your answer. Perfect! Thanks @uvgroovy

Answer (score 4):

This is one way:

```
lst = [[450, 455, 458], [452, 454, 457], [451, 453]]

res = {i: {w: None if w == v[0] else v[0] for w in v}
          for i, v in enumerate(lst)}
```

**Result**

```
{0: {450: None, 455: 450, 458: 450},
 1: {452: None, 454: 452, 457: 452},
 2: {451: None, 453: 451}}
```

**Explanation**

- Use ternary statement to determine whether you choose `None` or `v[0]`.
- Use `enumerate` to extract index of nested list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension here:

```
>>> result = [[450, 455, 458], [452, 454, 457], [451, 453]]

>>> dict(enumerate({**{i: a[0] for i in a[1:]}, **{a[0]: None}}
                   for a in result))

{0: {450: None, 455: 450, 458: 450},
 1: {452: None, 454: 452, 457: 452},
 2: {451: None, 453: 451}}
```

Note: this uses ["extended"](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448) iterable unpacking, which was introduced in Python 3.5.  `z = {**x, **y}` merges dictionaries `x` and `y`.

Each `a` is a sublist of `result`.  You want to use `a[0]` as the value for the 1st elements and above, and None for the 0th element.

The assumption here is that you only want the 0th element of the sublist to have a corresponding None value.  (If the 0th element were repeated, somewhere, it would use the 0th element as its value, as in @jpp's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

```
# the nice solutions were already given, so by foot:

d = {}
result = [[450, 455, 458], [452, 454, 457], [451, 453]]

for idx,l in enumerate(result): # returns the index and the sublists data
    rMin = min(l)
    d[idx] = {}  # create a inner dict at key idx
    for i in l:
        d[idx][i] = None if i == rMin else rMin   # fill inner dicts keys

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{0: {450: None, 455: 450, 458: 450},
 1: {452: None, 454: 452, 457: 452},
 2: {451: None, 453: 451}}
```